# custom validation, included in a module, will not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, validation

I am trying to include a custom validation across many models through a module, and I'm seeing some strange behavior. I wrote a custom validation called validates_as_unique which checks to see if a group of attributes is unique among records in the database. In a module called **FactBehaviors** I have:

```
module FactBehaviors
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.acts_as_fact
        extend ClassMethods
        include InstanceMethods
      end
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def self.included(base)
      if base.respond_to?(:validate_as_unique)
        base.send(:validates_as_unique)
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

The strangeness beings when I fire up the console and create a new, valid record (of type fact) *then* create another identical record. The validation passes (doesn't work properly). However, if I do reload! and try to create the same record again, the validation works and forbids me from creating the identical record.

I'm still a little murky as to the way rails loads classes, but I get the sense that that ignorance may be the problem here. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you add the content for your validates_as_unique validation? I believe there's already a validation that does this actually.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend ActiveRecord to add this module:

ActiveRecord::Base.extend(FactBehaviors)

to use it.